Bi-analytic bijections on $D(0,1)$

Let $f: D(0,1) \rightarrow D(0,1)$ be a bianalytic bijection such that $f(0)=0$.


Show that exists some $\omega \in S^1$ such that
$$(\forall z \in D(0,1)) : f(z)=\omega z$$

As $f$ is analytic,
$$g(z)=\begin{cases} \frac{f(z)}{z}; z \neq 0 \\[8 pt]  f'(0); z=0\end{cases}$$
is analytic on $D(0,1)$; I want to show that $g$ is constant on $D(0,1)-\{0\}$; if I could find $z_0 \in D(0,1)-\{0\}$ such that $|f(z_0)|=|z_0|$ then by the maximum principle, $g$ would be constant on $D(0,1)-\{0\}$ because I also know that:
$$\sup_{|z|\leq R}|g(z)| < \frac{1}{R} \implies \sup_{|z| <1 }|g(z)| \leq \lim_{R \rightarrow1}\frac{1}{R}=1$$
Any suggestions on using bianaliticity of $f$?

By proving $|g| \leqslant 1$ you practically proved that $|f(z)| \leqslant |z|$. Doesn't a symmetrical argument give you the reverse inequality?

Rudin's RCA gives all bi-analytic bijections of $D(0,1)$.

@geetha290krm, excuse me, on which chapter could I find that characterization?

Do you know the Schwarz Lemma? It can be applied to $f$ and to $f^{-1}$ ...

@MartinR, Yes, should I show that exists a $z_0 \in D(0,1)-{0}$ such that $|f(z_0)|=|z_0|$?

The Schwarz lemma can be applied to $f$, so that
$$
 \forall z \in D(0,1) : |f(z)| \le |z| \, .
$$
And the Schwarz lemma can also be applied to $f^{-1}$, so that
$$
\begin{align}
 & \forall w \in D(0,1) : |f^{-1}(w)| \le |w| \, \\
\implies & \forall z \in D(0,1) : |z| \le |f(z)| \, .
\end{align}
$$
It follows that $|f(z)| = |z|$ for all $z$, and in that case the Schwarz lemma states that $f$ is a rotation $f(z) = \omega z$ with some $\omega$ of modulus one.
